# scraping 2 websites (same structure) with basically the same code but 2 different results?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, web-frontend

I scraped 2 websites:

1. https://www.brookings.edu/blog/future-development/2018/01/26/delivering-inclusive-urban-access-3-uncomfortable-truths/
   [image]
2. https://www.nytimes.com/2018/01/25/opinion/sunday/silicon-valley-immortality.html
   [image]

Before scraping, I created the following class and function:

```
class Content:
    def __init__(self, url, title, body):
        self.url = url
        self.title = title
        self.body = body
def getPage(url):
    req = requests.get(url)
    return BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')
```

For the first website I used following code:

```
url = 'https://www.brookings.edu/blog/future-development/2018/01/26/delivering-inclusive-urban-access-3-uncomfortable-truths/'

bs = getPage(url)
title = bs.find('h1').text
body = bs.find('div', {'class': 'post-body'}).text
utb = Content(url, title, body)

print('Title: {}'.format(utb.title))
print('URL: {}\n'.format(utb.url))
print(utb.body)
```

Output:

> Title: Delivering inclusive urban access: 3 uncomfortable truths URL:
> https://www.brookings.edu/blog/future-development/2018/01/26/delivering-inclusive-urban-access-3-uncomfortable-truths/
>
> The past few decades have been filled with a deep optimism about the
> role of cities and suburbs across the world. These engines of economic
> growth host a majority of world population, are major drivers of
> economic innovation, and have created pathways to opportunities for
> untold amounts of people.
>
> Jeffrey Gutman Nonresident Senior Fellow - Global Economy and
> Development
>
> Adie Tomer Fellow - Metropolitan Policy Program
>
> Twitter AdieTomer
>
> But all is not well within our so-called Urban Century. Rapid
> urbanization, rising gentrification, concentrated poverty, and
> shortages of basic infrastructure have combined to create spatial
> inequity in cities and suburbs across the globe. The challenges of
> housing, moving, and employing so many people have led to longer
> travel times, rising housing costs, and unsustainable public spending.
> Moreover, policymakers are questioning traditional policies and
> approaches. The past couple years, we’ve led a project at
> Brookings—Moving to Access—that responds to these spatial challenges
> by promoting the idea of connecting people to opportunities as a new
> foundational principle for 21st century urban development. This
> principle of accessibility is meant to be a corollary to the natural
> questions we ask ourselves everyday about the communities where we
> live: Is this the best location to access employment? Are there nearby
> schools and health services? Is there a market in the neighborhood?
> How can I get from here to there? Such choices are valid for those
> with sufficient income. But what about those with more limited
> resources and thus choices in terms of affordable housing and
> affordable transport? ...

For second website I used the following code:

```
url = 'https://www.nytimes.com/2018/01/25/opinion/sunday/silicon-valley-immortality.html'

bs = getPage(url)
title = bs.find('h1').text

body = bs.find('section', {'name': 'articleBody', 'class': 'meteredContent'}).text

utb = Content(url, title, body)

print('Title: {}'.format(utb.title))
print('URL: {}\n'.format(utb.url))
print(utb.body)
```

Output:

> Title: The Men Who Want to Live Forever URL:
> https://www.nytimes.com/2018/01/25/opinion/sunday/silicon-valley-immortality.html
>
> Would you like to live forever? Some billionaires, already invincible
> in every other way, have decided that they also deserve not to die.
> Today several biotech companies, fueled by Silicon Valley fortunes,
> are devoted to “life extension” — or as some put it, to solving “the
> problem of death.”It’s a cause championed by the tech billionaire
> Peter Thiel, the TED Talk darling Aubrey de Gray, Google’s
> billion-dollar Calico longevity lab and investment by Amazon’s Jeff
> Bezos. The National Academy of Medicine, an independent group,
> recently dedicated funding to “end aging forever.”As the longevity
> entrepreneur Arram Sabeti told The New Yorker: “The proposition that
> we can live forever is obvious. It doesn’t violate the laws of
> physics, so we can achieve it.” Of all the slightly creepy aspects to
> this trend, the strangest is the least noticed: The people publicly
> championing life extension are mainly men.Not all of them, of course.
> In 2009, Elizabeth Blackburn received the Nobel Prize for her work on
> telomeres, protein caps on chromosomes that may be a key to
> understanding aging. Cynthia Kenyon, the vice president for aging
> research at Calico, studied life extension long before it was cool;
> her form ...

As you can see, the result from the second website don't have "spacing" between paragraphs.

Thank you for any clarifying explanation, why the same code used on 2 websites with basically the same structure outputs differently (difference in spacing between paragraphs)?

Answer (score 0):

The page source of the first article has line breaks (showing up in BS as `\n`) in the actual html document:

[image]

whereas the New York Times piece doesn't (spacing handled in CSS). It's all inline:

[image]

Comment: I was aware that in the BS of 2nd article don't have the line break. But after I checked my the website structure (see my first 2 screenshots), I could see that both of them have a normal structure (Parent's parent >> parent >> children >> children's children >> ...). That means before parsing with BeautifulSoup, there is a "structure". That's why I dismissed this possibility. How come is there such differentiation? Or in which step is such differentiation being made? Thank you for clarifying that.

Comment: Google Chrome will format according to its own rules. Page source is what Beautiful Soup reads. You've got that the wrong way around, HTML structure comes before Chrome gets to it. Chrome parses HTML/CSS and puts it into a common structure (e.g. stripping line breaks)